# How can I add a legend while plotting multiple geopandas dataframes in the same subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, spatial, geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe `world` which I created using:

```
import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
```

I created two different geodataframes for `usa` and `china` as shown below:

```
usa = world[world.name == "United States of America"]

china = world[world.name == "China"]
```

I want to plot the USA as blue and China as red in the map. I plotted it using the following line of code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20, 8))
world.plot(ax = ax, color = "whitesmoke", ec = "black")
usa.plot(ax = ax, color = "blue", label = "USA")
china.plot(ax = ax, color = "red", label = "China")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

It looks as follows:
[image]

I want to add legends stating blue for the USA and red for China. Therefore, I gave labels as shown in the code above. However, I get the following warning:

> No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists
> whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is
> called with no argument.

I am not able to add the legend. How can I add the legends for the USA and China in this plot? Is it possible using geopandas and matplotlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used `geopandas`, however looking at the result is appears that those filled areas are `PathCollection`, which are not supported on legends. But we can create legend artists:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
usa = world[world.name == "United States of America"]
china = world[world.name == "China"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
world.plot(ax = ax, color = "whitesmoke", ec = "black")
usa.plot(ax = ax, color = "blue", label = "USA")
china.plot(ax = ax, color = "red", label = "China")

lines = [
    Line2D([0], [0], linestyle="none", marker="s", markersize=10, markerfacecolor=t.get_facecolor())
    for t in ax.collections[1:]
]
labels = [t.get_label() for t in ax.collections[1:]]
ax.legend(lines, labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]